# int main(int argc, char **argv ) with < stdin > stdout in c

Tags: c, stdin, argv

If I want to use one exe file with the command like this:

```
1.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

To enter the file name into the C program which is used to modify the input file and output file, will it work?

I have tried with `1.exe input.txt output.txt` it works.

However, when I changed it into `1.exe < input.txt > output.txt`, it could not open the file.

Even, I increased the pointer, `argv[1]` to `argv[2]` and `argv[2]` to `argv[4]`.

So, what should I do with `1.exe < input.txt > output.txt` command?

Comment: I don't use `.exe` files. What is your point?

Comment: I don't understand.  'I have tried with 1.exe input.txt output.txt it works' - why didn't you just stop there?

Comment: This is not really a [c] question.  The two commands you provided *have different meaning to the shell*.  Although you can write programs that exhibit the same behavior in these two cases, there's no reason to expect to get that for free.  Neither in C nor in any other language.

Comment: The redirections specified by `< input.txt > output.txt` are handled by the shell before your program is launched. Your program doesn't see those filenames in `argv`, but it can access the opened files via `stdin` and `stdout`. Please read the docs for your shell for further details on redirection.

Comment: Perhaps you want `1.exe "< input.txt" "> output.txt"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this: `1.exe input.txt output.txt`, it passes input.txt as the first argument to 1.exe and output.txt as the second argument.

This is different from `1.exe < input.txt > output.txt`, which puts the contents of input.txt on stdin and writes stdout to output.txt.

The program 1.exe is expecting to be given the names of files which it then opens and operates on.  It does not expect to read from stdin and write to stdout.  If that's what you want to do, you need to modify the program to make it do that.